# Data being committed to one table but not the other (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having a bit of a weird problem in that in my PHP code for my signup page only one of the two statements are being committed to a table. and as a result, users cannot activate their accounts.

I'm almost certain it relates to my PHP because in firebug I'm getting a 500 error, however even with PHP error logging enabled and server logging enabled It's showing up nothing in the file. So i'm at a loss and though some talented web dev out there might be able to see the problem I'm having.

I've made an echo statement right before the data is inserted to the database, and it's all there for me to see. My echo statement `echo "'$u' '$e' '$p_hash' '$cn' '$c' '$ip'";` is showing me that my variables are carrying a value. I would post a screenshot but apparently I don't have the reputation to do that, but everything shows up on the echo statement just before the insert statement.

and the insert that goes with that is this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, compname, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck) VALUES ('$u','$e','$p_hash','$cn','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
```

the insert statement after this works fine and that data goes into the table. that statement is as follows.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

and this is the PHP I used to make my tables

```
$tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
              id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              username VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
              email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
              password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
              companyname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
              website VARCHAR (255) NULL,
              country VARCHAR (255) NULL,
              userlevel ENUM ('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
              avatar VARCHAR (255) NULL,
              ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
              signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
              lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
              notescheck DATETIME NOT NULL,
              activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              UNIQUE KEY username (username,email) 
            )";
```

I'm new to web development but I've never seen this before, and its weird. I contacted my hosting company and they said nothing was going on with their database so it's all fine on that end, It's not my ajax as the variables are being passed in because of my echo statement, and only one insert statement works. Thanks a lot for the help in advance, I'll be replying as quick as I can.

If you need any additional information I'd be happy to supply it!

Cheers,

Comment: Are you not doing any error checking for your queries at all? Go read up on how to do that and how to _ask_ MySQL for what error may have occured.

Comment: I see `compname` in your SQL INSERT, but `companyname` in your table definition

Comment: Do some error checking and the problem will reveal itself. Or don't if you want other people here to do your work for you.

Comment: How could I not see that! Badoing!, thanks so much fella. I'll sleep soundly tonight!

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, `users` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. As such you need to use backticks when referencing it as a table. In fact, it's recommended that all tables/columns are marked with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `compname`, `country`, `ip`, `signup`, `lastlogin`, `notescheck`) VALUES ('$u','$e','$p_hash','$cn','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())
--          ^     ^ Note the backticks
```

Also, there seems to be a mismatch between your table definition and the insert statements (`companyname` vs `compname`).

Last but not least, you should be using **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**

---

In any case, you should be checking for errors!

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
if (!$query) {
    //Something bad happened!
    var_dump($db_conx->error); //Show error details.
}
```

Comment: No [it isn't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) - neither `USER` nor `USERS`

Comment: Oh thanks so much, I've been having so much trouble with users recently, that would be why. Cheers!

Comment: @AlmaDo: I've added the other things that are possible as well. I think it's the `compname/companyname` mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your names (table and field) with ` like this:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `compname`, `country`, `ip`, `signup`, `lastlogin`, `notescheck`)
```

It tells mysql parser that it's actually field names and prevents it from treating your field names as statements. For example, password is a statement, and that's most probably why your query doesn't execute.